# ANOVA "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases"

Tags: r

I have this error when I write this ANOVA:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Code  I ran,

```
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = df, dv =value, wid = Before.ID,
  within = c(series, Before.Treatments)
  )
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

This is an instance of my data frame. I have seen that it might be an error with the wid, but I can't figure it out

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want to ferform the test, but when I check

```
df %>%
  select(Before.ID, Series, Before.Treatments) %>%
  distinct %>% dim

[1] 27  3
```

There are no `ID`'s to compare `within`. Trying `between`, it will give you a result.

```
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = df, dv =value, wid = Before.ID,
  between = c(Series, Before.Treatments)
)
get_anova_table(res.aov)

ANOVA Table (type III tests)

                    Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1                   Series   1  23 31.134 1.12e-05     * 0.575
2        Before.Treatments   1  23  0.681 4.18e-01       0.029
3 Series:Before.Treatments   1  23  1.994 1.71e-01       0.080
```